# React on image in only one channel discord python

Tags: python, image, discord, png

So I made this code which detects in discord if the user send an image. I want to only monitor one channel and not all. I dont know how to achieve this

```
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.attachments) > 0: #Checks if there are attachments
        for file in message.attachments:
            for ext in pic_ext:
                if file.filename.endswith(ext):
                    print(f"This message has an Image called: {file.filename}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def on_message(message):
          if message.channel.name is not "channel_name":
           return
# alternatively it can be used for channel.id too
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20channel#textchannel) for the properties available for a `TextChannel` you may further introduce an `if` statement for any such checks.